# How to execute multiple commands in system() , also using a variable

Tags: c, bash, printf, system

Ok so I've googled for an hour or more and I still didn't solved my issue.

I have these 3 bash commands:

1. `find . -name "file_name" -exec du -h {} \;`   -> gives me the file's size
2. `ls -l --time-style='+%d/%m/%Y' "file_name" | awk '{print $6}'` -> last modiffied date
3. `ls -l "file_name"|cut -d" " -f1` -> file's permissions

And I want to execute these 3 commands at a time using `system();`

```
Output example :
```

File size : ...

Last modiffied date : ...

File permissions : ...

**My attempt :**

```
char command[256];
char file_name[]={"myfile.txt"};
sprintf(command,"find . -name %s -exec du -h {} \; &&
        ls -l --time-style='+%D/%m/%Y' %s | awk '{print $6}' &&
        ls -l %s | cut -d' ' -f1",
        file_name,file_name,file_name);
system((char*)command);
```

**NOTES : I don't have to worry about the file's path because I'm using files from the same directory I execute my c program.**

**Compilation error : 'Sh: && is not expected'**

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but could you just use the `stat()` API instead?

Comment: If you want to include a literal `%` in a format string, you need to use two of them `%%`. Probably `%D/%m/%Y` is causing you some sort of problem. It would be a lot easier to answer your question if you specified exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: And, yes, you should use `stat()` as @keithmo suggests, instead of the Rube Goldberg you built out of `system()`

Comment: It looks like you've incorrectly terminated the format string in `sprintf`. The string should end at `f1`. Also, you've broken the string across multiple lines which should not even compile. So as already stated by rici, it would really help if you told us what your actual problem is (ie, you haven't actually asked a specific question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to add a percent sign in front of each percent sign you wanted in your command, otherwise it would be interpreted by sprintf as a print-mask introducer.  Additionally, you need to add a back-slash in front of each back-slash you want in your command, otherwise it would be interpreted by sprintf as an introducer (e.g. for \n etc.).  Additionally, I modified the sprintf second argument (i.e. the string)... I put ending quotes at the end of each physical line in your code, and at the beginning of the next physical line in your code.

Here is an example that may be what you are looking for (at least it compiles and runs):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char command[256];
    char file_name[] = "myfile.txt";


    sprintf(command, "find . -name %s -exec du -h {} \\; && "
            "ls -l --time-style='+%%D/%%m/%%Y' %s | awk '{print $6}' && "
            "ls -l %s | cut -d' ' -f1",
            file_name,
            file_name,
            file_name);
    printf("command: -->%s<--\n\n\n", command);
    system((char*)command);
}
```